# Exclude All Records for a Specific ID if One Record Contains a NULL

Tags: sql-server-2008

How do I exclude all rows that correspond to a row that had a `null` value?

```
-----------------------------------
| 0000139 | null | 10-01-2012 |
----------------------------------
| 0000139 | 95 | 10-02-2012 |
-----------------------------------
```

I do not only want to exclude the row with the null but all others as well.

Comment: Can you give us a little more detail? When you say "correspond" it seems you mean the next row in your dataset - can you confirm that? And what's the query you're using to retrieve the data?

Comment: What is your criteria for "related" rows?

Comment: select id_number,date,score from Scores This will give me all records well if they have a null as a score i want to eliminate all their entries not just the one with the null score. So one kid can have 20 entries on different dates but bc he didn't have one score I want to elinate all his 20 scores not just the one null score.

Comment: So you want to exclude all records with a NULL in *any* column or just the 4th column? And then exclude the following record as well?

Comment: I want to exclude all kids who have a null score, not just that one entry but all their entries.

Comment: Wait, do you want to exclude those rows from your query, or do you want to *delete* those rows from the table? There's a big difference, and "remove" is ambiguous - please be clear about your intention.

Comment: exclude sorry...not remove from a table

Answer (score 4):

```
;WITH x AS (SELECT key FROM dbo.table WHERE some_column IS NULL)
  SELECT col1, col2, etc.
  FROM dbo.table AS t
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM x WHERE key = t.key);
```

Comment: Updated my answer since I now realize that "remove" didn't actually mean "delete." Would be great to get the benefit of the doubt on that, especially since I was the one who tried to get clarification from the OP, instead of a down-vote.

Comment: As of my writing this, it looks like you'd want it to be `WHERE key NOT IN` instead (or `NOT EXISTS`); this query would return all rows where there was a NULL row for that key.

Answer (score 0):

The below code identifies all kids who have NULL values for at least one test score and excludes them from the query results.

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
    ( KidId INT NOT NULL
    , Score INT NULL);

INSERT INTO #Test (KidId, Score)
SELECT KidId
    , Score
FROM (VALUES
        (1, 100), (1, 50), (1, 10)
    , (2, NULL), (2, NULL), (2, NULL)
    , (3, 100), (3, NULL), (3, 40)) sub (KidId, Score);

SELECT *
FROM #Test trgt
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
    FROM #Test src
    WHERE trgt.KidId = src.KidId
    AND src.Score IS NULL);
```

Comment: This is a great example and is exactly my case but I wish to exclude kidId 3 as well bc he has one score of null. Using this case I would only like to have KidID 1 in my results bc he is the only kid without a null value for score. How do I adjust the query to remove both kid 2 and 3.

Comment: SELECT *
FROM #Test
WHERE KidId NOT IN
    (SELECT KidId
    FROM #Test
     WHERE Score IS NULL
    GROUP BY KidId
  );

Comment: I adjusted the code to match this requirement.  Also, I used a NOT EXISTS since this (1) indicates the code intent a bit more clearly and (2) can perform better under some specific circumstances.